# Desarrollar una aplicación Kiosk-mode para android

Tags: java, android

Buenas, estaba desarrollando una aplicación para que funcionase como un kiosk-mode en android, como algunas aplicaciones disponibles actualmente. Mi problema es que quiero bloquear los botones físicos del teléfono desde el background, ya que al abrir esta app, se lanzaría otra y en esa aplicación ya debería estar todo bloqueado.

He buscado y buscado pero no consigo encontrar nada

Comment: Por favor añade información adicional como el código con el que lanzas esta nueva app o cómo estás intentando bloquear los controles actualmente.

Comment: Podrias ser más concreto, mostrar el código que has intentado, y explicar mejor lo que deseas.